# Get MAC address using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, mac-address

Currently all the solution mentioned for getting the MAC address always use eth0.
But what if instead of eth0 my interfaces start with eth1. Also on OS X the interface names are different.
Also the interface eth0 may be present but is unused. i.e. not active, it doesn't have an IP.

So is there a way I could get the MAC address for the first available interface that is Active.(i.e. it has an inet address, I even don't want one having inet6).

For E.g

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <some addr>
          inet6 addr: <some addr> Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:123
          RX packets:123 errors:123 dropped:123 overruns:123 frame:123
          TX packets:123 errors:123 dropped:123 overruns:123 carrier:123
          collisions:123 txqueuelen:123 
          RX bytes:123 (123 MB)  TX bytes:123 (123 KB)
          Interrupt:123 Memory:00000000-00000000

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <some addr>
          inet addr:<some addr>  Bcast:<some addr>  Mask:<some addr>
          inet6 addr: <some addr> Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:123 Metric:123
          RX packets:123 errors:123 dropped:123 overruns:123 frame:123
          TX packets:123 errors:123 dropped:123 overruns:123 carrier:123
          collisions:123 txqueuelen:123 
          RX bytes:123 (123 MB)  TX bytes:123 (123 KB)
          Interrupt:123 Memory:00000000-00000000
```

NOTE : I have changed the values of the output.

So in this case I want the HWaddr for eth1 and not eth0.
How do I find it ? Also it should work on all the Linux flavours.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Observe that the interface name and the MAC address are the first and last fields on a line with no leading whitespace.

If one of the indented lines contains `inet addr:` the latest interface name and MAC address should be printed.

```
ifconfig -a |
awk '/^[a-z]/ { iface=$1; mac=$NF; next }
    /inet addr:/ { print iface, mac }'
```

Note that multiple interfaces could meet your criteria. Then, the script will print multiple lines. (You can add `; exit` just before the final closing brace if you always only want to print the first match.)

Comment: If your target is Linux only, it would be more robust to examine the pertinent `/proc` entries directly; but since you mention OSX also, I suppose that approach is ruled out.

Answer (score 97):

You can do as follows

```
ifconfig <Interface ex:eth0,eth1> | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

Also you can get MAC for all interface as follows

```
cat /sys/class/net/*/address
```

For particular interface like for eth0

```
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address
```

Answer (score 61):

The best Linux-specific solution is to use sysfs:

```
$ IFACE=eth0
$ read MAC </sys/class/net/$IFACE/address
$ echo $IFACE $MAC
eth0 00:ab:cd:12:34:56
```

This method is extremely clean compared to the others and spawns no additional processes since `read` is a builtin command for POSIX shells, including non-BASH shells. However, if you need portability to OS X, then you'll have to use `ifconfig` and `sed` methods, since OS X does not have a virtual filesystem interface like sysfs.

Comment: This should be the best answer !

Answer (score 52):

```
$ ip route show default | awk '/default/ {print $5}'
```

return: **eth0** (my online interface)

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/$(ip route show default | awk '/default/ {print $5}')/address
```

return: **ec:a8:6b:bd:55:05** (macaddress of the eth0, my online interface)

[Terminal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa6Zp.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post more info on your answer. What is it doing and why.

Answer (score 20):

On a modern GNU/Linux system you can **see the available network interfaces** listing the content of `/sys/class/net/`, for example:

```
$ ls /sys/class/net/
enp0s25  lo  virbr0  virbr0-nic  wlp2s0
```

You can **check if an interface is `up`** looking at `operstate` in the device directory. For example, here's how you can see if `enp0s25` is up:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/enp0s25/operstate
up
```

You can then **get the MAC address** of that interface with:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/enp0s25/address 
ff:00:ff:e9:84:a5
```

**For example**, here's a simple bash script that prints MAC addresses for active interfaces:

```
#!/bin/bash
# getmacifup.sh: Print active NICs MAC addresses
D='/sys/class/net'
for nic in $( ls $D )
do
    echo $nic
    if  grep -q up $D/$nic/operstate
    then
        echo -n '   '
        cat $D/$nic/address
    fi
done
```

And here's its output on a system with an ethernet and a wifi interface:

```
$ ./getmacifup.sh
enp0s25
   ff:00:ff:e9:84:a5
lo
wlp2s0
```

For details see the [Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-net)

---

Remember also that from 2015 most GNU/Linux distributions switched to `systemd`, and don't use `ethX` interface naming scheme any more - now they use a more robust naming convention based on the hardware topology, see:

- [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)
- [systemd/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/3f65d73149cd0f64eb3fdb0c71f55f6c1133fefe/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c)

Answer (score 7):

**Simply run:**

```
ifconfig | grep ether | cut -d " " -f10
```

OR

```
ip a | grep ether | cut -d " " -f6
```

These two example commands will grep all lines with "ether" string and cut the mac address (that we need) following the number spaces (specified in the -f option) of the grepped portion.

Tested on different Linux flavors

Answer (score 4):

I know that is a little bit dated, but with basic commands, we can take the mac address of an interface:

```
ip link show eth0 | grep link/ether | awk '{print $2}'
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: wow! thank you! That was exactly what I was look for to get the private networking mac address on vultr.

Answer (score 3):

oh, if you want only the mac ether mac address, you can use that:

```
ifconfig | grep "ether*" | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '\t' | cut -c 6-42
```

(work on macintosh)

- `ifconfig` -- get all info
- `grep` -- keep the line with address
- `tr` -- clean all
- `cut` -- remove the "ether" to have only the address

Comment: `tr -d` can remove multiple characters in one go.  The regex `ether*` matches `ethe` followed by zero or more occurrences of `r`; I suppose you really mean `grep 'ether'` which matches the literal string anywhere on the input line.  `ifconfig | grep ether | tr -d ' \t' | cut -c 6-42`

Comment: Just like the Awk in my answer, which does pretty much the same thing in a single process instead of a pipeline invoking multiple processes.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me because my devices are in a balance-rr bond. Querying either would say the same MAC address with `ip l l`, `ifconfig`, or `/sys/class/net/${device}/address`, so one of them is correct, and one is unknown.

But this works if you haven't renamed the device (any tips on what I missed?):

```
udevadm info -q all --path "/sys/class/net/${device}"
```

And this works even if you rename it (eg. `ip l set name x0 dev p4p1`):

```
cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
```

or my ugly script that makes it more parsable (untested driver/os/whatever compatibility):

```
awk -F ': ' '
         $0 == "" && interface != "" {
            printf "%s %s %s\n", interface, mac, status;
            interface="";
            mac=""
         }; 
         $1 == "Slave Interface" {
            interface=$2
         }; 
         $1 == "Permanent HW addr" {
            mac=$2
         };
         $1 == "MII Status" {
            status=$2
         };
         END {
            printf "%s %s %s\n", interface, mac, status
         }' /proc/net/bonding/bond0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
 ip a | grep link/ether | awk -F " " '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used command hciconfig with two greps to separate the PC Mac address and I **saved the MAC address to variable**:

`PCMAC=$( hciconfig -a | grep -E 'BD Address:' | grep -Eo '[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}' )`

You can also use this command to **check if MAC address is in valid format.** Note, that only big chars A-F are allowed and also you need to add input for this grep command:

`grep -E '[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2}'`

Answer (score 0):

This was the only thing that worked for me on Armbian:

```
dmesg | grep -oE 'mac=.*\w+' | cut -b '5-'
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an alternative answer in case the ones listed above don't work for you.  You can use the following solution(s) as well, which was found [here](https://www.webhostinghero.com/how-to-find-your-ip-address-and-mac-address-in-linux/):

```
ip addr
```

OR

```
ip addr show
```

OR

```
ip link
```

All three of these will show your MAC address(es) next to `link/ether`.  I stumbled on this because I had just done a fresh install of Debian 9.5 from a USB stick without internet access, so I could only do a very minimal install, and received

```
-bash: ifconfig: command not found
```

when I tried some of the above solutions.  I figured somebody else may come across this problem as well.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Get MAC adress for eth0:

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 | grep HWADDR | cut -c 9-25
```

Example:

```
[me@machine ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 | grep HWADDR | cut -c 9-25
55:b5:00:10:be:10
```

Comment: `grep` can read the input file just fine.  Avoid the [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: Limited to Redhat derivatives.

Comment: this could potentially be wrong due to ifcfg-eth0 only being a config file for the specific interface/mac address, not the actual interface/mac.