# Processing ifconfig and hostname output and frame it in single line for multiple hosts

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I'm trying to filter remote machine mac address , IP and hostname from 100 machines. Initially I'm capturing the information using below command.

```
$for i in `cat IP`;do in ssh root@$IP "ifconfig eth0 && hostname " ;done

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:MN:77:TR:XX:ZZ
          inet addr:192.168.122.25  Bcast:192.168.122.255  
          Mask:255.255.224.0
test.com-112304
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:TT:77:MM:XX:YY
          inet addr:192.168.122.22  Bcast:192.168.122.255  
          Mask:255.255.224.0
test.com-11035
```

Initially the output redirect to one file. from their I need to process output which comes in the above format.

I can able to accomplish to print IP and mac by line as follows

```
$cat input | awk '/HWaddr/{printf $NF;printf " ";getline;print $2;}' | cut -c1-18,24-

00:MN:77:TR:XX:ZZ 192.168.122.25
00:TT:77:MM:XX:YY 192.168.122.22
```

Actually I want to include hostname along with the output as follows

```
00:MN:77:TR:XX:ZZ 192.168.122.25  test.com-112304
00:TT:77:MM:XX:YY 192.168.122.22  test.com-11035
```

test.com will be common name for all hostname. I tried redirect both output in two variable and called as follows , but no luck.

```
a=`cat input | awk '/HWaddr/{printf $NF;printf " ";getline;print $2;}' | cut -c1-18,24-`
b=`grep test.com input`
echo $a $b  | xargs -n2
```

Please shed some views

Comment: If you could post the output of your command we could then give you more clear solution for your output, as of now it is not clear.

Comment: You make things too complicated I think.  When `ssh` to the remote server, you can output the `Mac address` of `eth0` and the hostname at one line.

Comment: see what pasting your code to https://shellcheck.net shows as needing fixing. I don't see that you use the `i` variable you declare in `for i` among others.j Agree with above comments. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to filter remote machine mac address , IP and hostname from 100 machines.

1. Machine mac address, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828413/get-mac-address-using-shell-script): `cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address`
2. You have `hostname` utility, why don't you just `hostname -i`? You can parse `ifconfig | grep inet | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/addr://'` and hope ifconfig versions are the same across all machines (some ifconfig verions return `inet <ip>` some return `inet addr:<ip>` like yours).
3. Hostname with `hostname`

Putting together:

```
echo $(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address) $(ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | awk '{print $2}') $(hostname)
```

Executing a command for each line in some file is a job for [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) and remember about properly escaping your arguments:

```
cat IP | xargs -n1 -I{} ssh root@{} 'echo $(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address) $(ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | awk '\''{print $2}'\'' | sed '\''s/addr://'\'') $(hostname)'
```

If you really have 100 machines, [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) might interest you.

If you really have that "input" file and you can't change it, you may parse it like this:

```
sed 's/eth0/#eth0/' input \
| xargs -d'#' -n1 -- bash -c '{ echo "$1" | grep HWaddr | awk "{print \$5}"; echo "$1" | grep inet | awk "{print \$2}" | sed "s/addr://"; echo "$1" | grep "^test.com"; } | tr "\n" " "; echo' --
```

And [this hurts my eyes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor):

```
for i in `cat IP`; then
```

Comment: this is customized and old kernel  and there is no such location /sys , might be hardcoded. The only way to check by ifconfig <interface>. let me test this and come back to us

Comment: cool it worked like a charm, many thanks :) the last sed one :) its  complicated too :p